# default landing page is not showing in react.js

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

path="/" works perfectly in local but when i have hosted it with the github pages.While visitig the site through the link it only shows the navigation and footer.

This is the code of my App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import Hero from './pages/Hero'
import Aboutme from './pages/Aboutme'
import Project from './pages/Project'
import Service from './pages/Service'
import Contact from './pages/Contact'
import './App.sass'
import './style/Responsive.sass'
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Routes, Route}from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav></Nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={ <Hero></Hero> }></Route>
        <Route path='/aboutme' element={<Aboutme></Aboutme>}></Route>
        <Route path='/project' element={<Project />}></Route>
        <Route path='/service' element={<Service />}></Route>
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

this is package.json file

```
{
  "homepage": "https://Ashimgautam356.github.io/ReactPortfolio",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am expecting to get render all the components like navigation, Hero component(body), footer of the site.

Comment: Did you try with `<Router basename="/ReactPortfolio">` ?

Comment: No ,I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi! did you tried unsing HashRouter as I mentioned in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen? Because GitHub Pages does not support browser history like your browser does. In our case, the route https://tomerpacific.github.io/starter-project/about doesn't help GitHub Pages understand where to point the user (since it is a frontend route).

source [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/)

So you have to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` if you want to deploy your app to GitHub